# using Carbon to know if a time falls between two points of time or not

Tags: php, datetime, laravel

I am using Laravel. I have just come across `Carbon` which was already there in vendors folder. I did some quick search and found that it is a great extension from PHP Date time.

Somewhere in my application, I needed a logic that will check if a given time falls between two points of time. Lets say, I want to check if 10:00 falls under the time time 9:55 and 10:05. Surely, it falls but how should I use that logic with the help of Carbon.

By default `Carbon::now()` will return date and time in `2014-12-02 14:37:18` format. I was thinking if I could extract the time part only i.e `14:37:18` then I can compare two times to know whether the time under testing falls under the two points of time or not.

If i directly check two Carbon objects, it will try to check the year as well. But all I need is just the time part only.

And as a matter of fact, I am not even sure If the times (h:m:s) can directly can be compared or not through carbon.

Comment: examples of formatting and comparison found [here](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon)

Answer (score 29):

Yes there is a way to do this in Carbon, as just take a look on documentation [here](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/).

> To determine if the current instance is between two other instances you can use the aptly named between() method. The third parameter indicates if an equal to comparison should be done. The default is true which determines if its between or equal to the boundaries.

```
$first = Carbon::create(2012, 9, 5, 1);
$second = Carbon::create(2012, 9, 5, 5);
var_dump(Carbon::create(2012, 9, 5, 3)->between($first, $second));          // bool(true)
var_dump(Carbon::create(2012, 9, 5, 5)->between($first, $second));          // bool(true)
var_dump(Carbon::create(2012, 9, 5, 5)->between($first, $second, false));   // bool(false)
```

Comment: `between()` is not working for the second `var_dump(Carbon::create(2012, 9, 5, 5)->between($first, $second));          // bool(true)` since it returns `false`. Does it have to do with the timezone???

Comment: I am not a Carbon expert, will test out and come back.

Comment: Thanks. I found out why: I changed  the `today()` for the `now()` function. The former returns the date at midnight (`2016-05-13 00:00:00`) while the latter returns the date at the moment you are viewing the info (`2016-05-13 08:48:36`). Reference [here](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison).

Answer (score 4):

UNIX time is easier for this sort of task.

So you could use strtotime to convert your hipster representation to neckbeard representation and compare like a real man.
Since you only want to compare hours, you can hack this by using a relative time.

```
<?php
$now = time();
$startTime = strtotime( "12:10:24", $now );
$endTime = strtotime( "14:24:45", $now );
$point = strtotime("12:25:40", $now );
if( $point >= $startTime && $point <= $endTime )
{
  echo "Inside\n";
} else {
  echo "Outside\n";
}
?>
```

Output:

```
$ php test.php 2> /dev/null
Inside
```

Comment: I thought there would be much easier way through Carbon. I was hoping something like Carbon::(point)->between(start,end). Yeah, just that much. Still waiting if there's a way like that. But at the moment I just did what you told to do, 'like a real man'

Comment: Haha, sorry about the arrogant post, it was not meant that way :) I don't know about Carbon, and it might contain such a feature, otherwise, it would be a obvious feature to add to it. :)