# Getting the difference between dates - laravel php

Tags: php, laravel

I want to know number of days it has been since an account was created. What i do is, i take date user is created (create_at) from the current date(carbon::today) but i get an error

> > Object of class Carbon\Carbon could not be converted to int

```
 $get_reg_date = auth()->user()->created_at->toDateString();

         $num_of_days = 2;

         $two_days_after =  Carbon::parse($get_reg_date) - Carbon::today();

         return $two_days_after;
```

How can i achieve this please?

Comment: Check the docs for Carbon here.  https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using Carbon to know if a time falls under two points of time or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27245776/using-carbon-to-know-if-a-time-falls-under-two-points-of-time-or-not)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `diffInDays`. The `created_at` timestamp should already be a Carbon instance, so you can do it like this:

```
$days_since_created = Carbon::now()->diffInDays(auth()->user()->created_at);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `diffInDays()` instead.

```
auth()->user()->created_at->diffInDays() //by default uses today if none is passed

//otherwise
$the_day = Carbon::parse('yesterday');
auth()->user()->created_at->diffInDays($the_day);
```

gives you the absolute (non-negative) value of the difference. its up to you to find out.

Be aware that `Carbon::parse('today')->diffInDays(Carbon::parse('tomorrow'))` will give you 1 day, so if you are counting by days you might want to observe this *normal* behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
$daysPassed = Carbon::parse($get_reg_date)->diffInDays(Carbon::now());
```

I think this is what you want.